# How to acquire a token with Azure AD and MSAL in ASP.NET

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to authenticate a token using Azure AD. In a **console application**, I have no problem with this thanks to IConfidentialClientApplication:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Making the call...");
    RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static async Task RunAsync()
{
    AuthConfig config = AuthConfig.ReadJsonFromFile("appsettings.json");

    IConfidentialClientApplication app;

    app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
        .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
        .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))
        .Build();

    string[] ResourceIds = new string[] { config.ResourceId };

    AuthenticationResult result = null;

    try
    {
        result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(ResourceIds).ExecuteAsync();
    }
    ...
}
```

But in a Startup for an ASP.NET Core application, the app uses the standard IApplicationBuilder and the Configure(...) method can't take an IConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder as it doesn't exist.

In [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet), they create a `PublicClientApplicationBuilder`, but I don't want to start creating entirely new applications in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg/Startup.cs) of Startup for ASP.NET Core application for your reference. But as far as I know we can't get token directly in the Startup for ASP.NET Core application with "**IApplicationBuilder**". "**IApplicationBuilder**" and "**IConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder**" are two different concepts.

For your requirement, you can just import modules for msal and use the code you provided above or the code you mentioned in the [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet) to get the token.